# validateDOMNesting(...): <body> in Nextjs

Tags: next.js

I don't know ehy this warning coming again and again whenver I create new Next.js App.
[image]

Plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You placed your `<body>` in `<div>`. Change and double-check your `layouts` or `<>` structure.